# Why the expression (double.MinValue < double.MinValue + 1) returns false?

Tags: java, c#, .net

Consider the c# below code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Your code goes here
        Console.WriteLine(double.MinValue < double.MinValue + 1);
        Console.WriteLine(int.MinValue < int.MinValue + 1);
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
False
True
```

I know that

```
Console.WriteLine(double.MinValue + 1);
Console.WriteLine(double.MinValue);
```

will print the same `-1,79769313486232E+308` value.

My question is: **Why** this "unexpected" and curious behavior occurs? I hope the first line returns `true` too.

The below Java program, for example, returns the expected `true`:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Double.MIN_VALUE < Double.MIN_VALUE + 1);
    }
}
```

Why this different behavior?

Comment: Print out the two numbers and compare them yourself

Comment: @Servy thanks for your suggestion, but the question is about the "unexpected" and curious behavior. I know these two number will be the same when I print it, not the simply number comparison. The question is __why__ this occurs. Thanks.

Comment: If you knew that the two numbers are the same then why didn't you include that in your question?  If you know that the comparison has nothing at all to do with your question then *why include it in your question* and ask about it?  Additionally, if you knew what all of the relevant values were, and therefore knew that the java and C# constants represents radically different conceptual values, why ask about it?

Comment: @Servy right. I edited my question and added the required information. Looks better now?

Comment: @Servy _and therefore knew that the java and C# constants represents radically different conceptual values, why ask about it?_ No, I really don't know about the radical conceptual differences between Java and C# constants. Probably that's the reason I need to ask that question.

Comment: But you said that you've printed off the values and looked at them, so you know that they're radically different values.

Comment: @Servy No, they are exactly de same `-1,79769313486232E+308` value. Maybe the question should be why `double.MinValue + 1` and `double.MinValue` result in the same value. The answer provided by Louis is very appropriate.

Comment: No, java's Double.Min_Value is 2E-1074, not -1.7E308  Those two numbers are, again *very* different.  Louis also says as much in his answer, which you accepted, or you could have seen by simply printing out the values and looking at them before asking this question.

Comment: @Servy , I'm talking about the C# double.MinValue constant, not about the Java Double.Min_Value. The C# code `Console.WriteLine(double.MinValue + 1);
Console.WriteLine(double.MinValue);` returns the same `-1,79769313486232E+308` for both lines.

Comment: You're talking about *both*.  If you *only* want to talk about the C# code, then *only talk about the C# code*.  The whole quote of mine that you quoted was saying that the C# and Java code is completely different, and that you apparently knew as much (since you looked at the values) but your question indicates that you think they're the same, and that they should behave identically.  If you understand that the Java value is a completely different value, and why it should behave differently, then it makes no sense to ask why it doesn't behave the same as something very different.

Comment: No, I know that `double.MinValue` and `Double.Min_Value` represent different values. It is clear for me. My question is exactly about why `double.MinValue` and `double.MinValue + 1` result in the same value, as explained by Louis.

Comment: No, that's *not* what your question asks.  Your question shows the Java code and asks why it behaves differently from the C# code.

Comment: @Servy Okay, sorry if the question is not clear enough. The question is satisfactorily answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two min values are different things.

In Java, `MIN_VALUE` is the name for the smallest *positive* `double` value.  In C#, `MinValue` is the name for the double value less than all other finite values; in Java, that value would be `-Double.MAX_VALUE`.

And that value is so massively negative that adding `1` to it gets lost in the rounding.  `double` doesn't have enough precision to represent `MinValue` differently from `MinValue+1`. It's, roughly, -1800000....00 where there are *307* zeroes.  `double` can only represent, roughly, seventeen decimal digits of precision.  So adding one gets lost in the rounding.

Comment: To proof it you can try this line. Debug.WriteLine(double.MinValue == double.MinValue + 1); Result will be true.

Answer (score 1):

While both Java and C# implement the IEEE 754 specification for floating point computations, the minvalue constants are not the same.

- In Java it is the smallest **positive** value ([Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_VALUE))
- In C# it is the smallest value ([C# doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.minvalue.aspx))

You can try what happens (or rather "won't happen") here: http://weitz.de/ieee/